# filling table according to select tag options

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, fetch

Javascript beginner here, trying to learn by doing, my question is, here i have a table which is filled with information already and below it is select tag which is fetched from url. My question is i want to fill the table again but with the information of select tag ( depending on which option user choose from select tag, table gets filled with that information). here is select tags data

```
[
    {
        "id": "1111",
        "mygoals": "getmarried",
        "future": "married",

    },
    {
        "id": "2222",
        "mygoals": "getmarried",
        "future": "married",

    },
    {
        "id": "33333",
        "mygoals": "getmarried",
        "future": "married",

    }
]
```

[image]
Here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>

    </style>
 
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">

<table class="table table-responsive-sm "> 
  <thead> 
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>mygoals</th>
      <th>future</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody id="t">  
  </tbody>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>mygoals</th>
      <th>future</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody id="t2">  
  </tbody>
</table>

<select id="Select" name="name"></select>

</div>

<script>
fetch("https://asdasd.free.beeceptor.com/a", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "x-api-key": "p*****w"
    }
}).then(res =>{ 
    res.json().then(t => {
        console.log(t);
        var p ="";
        var p2 ="";


        p +="<tr>";
        p += "<td>"+t.id+"</td>";
        p += "<td>"+t.mygoals+"</td>";
        p += "<td>"+t.future+"</td>";
  p2 += "<td>"+t.id+"</td>";
  p2 += "<td>"+t.mygoals+"</td>";
  p2 += "<td>"+t.future+"</td></tr>";

        document.getElementById("t").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", p);
  document.getElementById("t2").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", p2);
 

    }
  )
}).catch(err => {
      console.log("ERROR: " + err);
});


fetch("https:******.com/", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "x-api-key": "p*****w"
    }
}).then(res =>{ 
    res.json().then(t => {
 
for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    var s = document.getElementById("Select");
    var o = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = t[i].id+ ' ' + t[i].mygoals;
 
    s.add(o);
}
    }
  )
   })
   
   
   
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: anybody here for help ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to populate a table with data, once you get the JSON from your XHR fetch, you can just iterate over the data and build table rows.

I am not sure what you mean, by populating the table by the select options. If need be, please provide a full use-case, but I interpret is as you want to fill the table based on the selection.

See the example below.

```js
const tableEl = document.querySelector('.table');
const selectEl = document.querySelector('#select');

// Only show the record that matched the selection.
selectEl.addEventListener('change', e => {
  // Or make a call to a different JSON endpoint...
  populateTableWithJSON(tableEl, getJsonData().filter(record => {
    return record.id === e.target.value;
  }));
});

populateTableWithJSON(tableEl, getJsonData());
populateSelectWithJSON(selectEl, getJsonData(), {
  idFn : r => r.id,
  displayFn : r => `${r.id} ${r.mygoals}`
});

function populateSelectWithJSON(select, jsonData, opts={}) {
  emptyElement(select);
  jsonData.forEach((record, index) => {
    let id = opts.idFn != null ? opts.idFn(record) : record.id || index;
    let text = opts.displayFn != null ? opts.displayFn(record) : record.text || '';
    select.appendChild(new Option(text, id));
  });
}

function populateTableWithJSON(table, jsonData) {
  let tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
  emptyElement(tbody);
  if (jsonData != null && jsonData.length > 0) {
    let headers = table.querySelectorAll('thead > tr th');
    let fields = headers.length
      ? Array.from(headers).map(th => th.textContent)
      : Object.keys(jsonData[0]);
    jsonData.forEach(record => {
      let tr = document.createElement('TR');
      fields.forEach(field => {
        let td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.textContent = record[field];
        tr.appendChild(td);
      });
      tbody.appendChild(tr);
    });
  }
}

function emptyElement(element) {
  while (element.firstChild) {
    element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
  }
}

function getJsonData() {
  return [{
    "id": "1111",
    "mygoals": "getmarried",
    "future": "married",
  }, {
    "id": "2222",
    "mygoals": "getmarried",
    "future": "married",
  }, {
    "id": "33333",
    "mygoals": "getmarried",
    "future": "married",
  }];
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-responsive-sm ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>mygoals</th>
        <th>future</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <select id="select" name="name"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: my question was clear, table is already filled with this : { "id": "145127236", "mygoals": "success", "future": "high", "dole": { "Key": "fhd699f" } }, and i want it get filled with select box data  depending on which option user choose from select tag

Comment: @walee So the select box load different datasets into the table? Where is your change listener on the select box? I do not see any events.

Comment: as you can see table has already data as json object, but select box is array of object

Comment: this is json data in select box : [
    {
        "id": "1111",
        "mygoals": "getmarried",
        "future": "married",

    },
    {
        "id": "2222",
        "mygoals": "getmarried",
        "future": "married",

    },
    {
        "id": "33333",
        "mygoals": "getmarried",
        "future": "married",

    }
], as i have already written, i want some simple code (to understand and learn)

Comment: @walee Your table does not actually have any JSON in it and I cannot see any example JSON for the table. I already populated the select box with the JSON data, now I am unsure what is supposed to be in the table.

Comment: @walee I updated the example to use a filter, is this the intended behavior?

Comment: i have added a picture of how it looks now, then when you choose from options of select box it should fill the table with that new data.